# Android: Creating options menu before it's called

Tags: android

I'm having trouble creating an options menu before I press the menu button. From what I can tell, onCreateOptionsMenu() is called when I press my menu button and the menu is then created. I need to access the menu before my menu button is pressed.

I got the usual so far. An onCreateOptionsMenu() below.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: "I need to access the menu before my menu button is pressed" -- why? Bear in mind that there is no MENU button on lots of devices.

Comment: I have an external device that calls a certain menuitem in the activity. Right now when the device wants to call a certain menuitem, a nullpointerexception is thrown because there is no menu created yet. If i pull up the menu on my android device, close it, then use my external device, it calls the menuitem successfully.

Comment: you should post the whole code and stacktrace rather than working around,  maybe someone will help with the real issue. Show the code where device calls a menuitem

Comment: "I have an external device that calls a certain menuitem in the activity" -- an "external device" is most certainly not reaching across time, space, operating systems, and process boundaries to "call a certain menuitem in the activity".

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work this way. From [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html): "If you've developed your application for Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to create the options menu when the user opens the menu for the first time. If you've developed for Android 3.0 and higher, the system calls `onCreateOptionsMenu()` when starting the activity, in order to show items to the action bar."

Answer (score 0):

You're really thinking about this the wrong way. If you need to "call a certain menu item in the Activity", just perform the function that the menu item would perform, don't try to programmatically "press" the menu item.

That is, if the menu option calls `finish()` on the Activity when pressed, simply call `finish()` instead of trying to virtually "press" a menu item.